# Checking whether a polynomial of degree at most 2 encompasses all possible polynomials of degree at most 2?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I found that the span of these three basis polynomials yielded $(a+b+c) + (a-b)x + (a+b)x^2$. The question is whether this spans the space of all polynomials of degree at most 2, and I think the answer is yes, but I'm not sure since I don't know whether there's a polynomial that fails the constraints of $(a+b+c), (a-b), (a+b)$. How do I check this?

Like, I'm pretty sure this polynomial - $(a+b) + (a-b)x + (a+b)x^2$ doesn't span, right? I can tell since the 1st and 3rd coefficients must be the same. Is there a system to check this?

I let $d=(a+b+c)$, so $a-b=d-2b-c$ and $a+b = d -c$ and by eye balling it, I seem good: I can choose $d$ for the constant term, then adjust by $c$ for the $x^2$ term, and then adjust $b$ for the $x$ term. Is this how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can translate your question to more standard vector spaces and matrices, and in multiple ways!

**First way**:

The set $\{(a+b+c) + (a-b)x + (a+b)x^2|a,b,c\in\mathbb R\}$ is the set of all polynomials if and only if, for every $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, the polynomial $$\alpha + \beta x + \gamma x^2$$ is in the set.

This means that what you are asking boils down to the question

> Does the system of equations $$\begin{align}a+b+c=\alpha\\ a-b=\beta\\ a+b=\gamma\end{align}$$ always have a solution?

which, if we define $\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$, can be translated into the question

> Does the equation $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ always have a solution if $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

**Second way:**

We can view the space of all polynomials as a vector space.
Because
$$(a+b+c) + (a-b)x + (a+b)x^2 = a\cdot(1+x+x^2) + b\cdot(1-x + x^2) + c\cdot 1,$$
we can write the set $$\{(a+b+c) + (a-b)x + (a+b)x^2|a,b,c\in\mathbb R\}$$ as the span of the set $\{1+x+x^2, 1-x+x^2, 1\}$.

Knowing the dimension of the space of polynomials of degree at most $2$ is three, we know that the span of a three-element set will be the whole space *if and only if* the three elements are linearly independent. Writing the three vectors in the basis $1,x,x^2$, the vectors are $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},$$ and the three vectors are independent if the matrix we get by stacking them up is of full rank, i.e. if the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&-1&0\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ is of full rank.

Note that this is the same matrix as before, and remember, for square matrices, the questions "is the matrix $A$ of full rank?" and "Does the equation $Ax=b$ always have a solution?" are *equivalent*, so this is the same condition as before!

**Third way**:

Let $\mathbb P_2[x]$ be the space of polynomials of degree at least $2$. Let $\mathcal A$ be the mapping defined as $$\mathcal A:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb P_2[x]\\
(a,b,c)\mapsto (a+b+c)+(a-b)x+(a+b)x^2$$

It is easy to see that $\mathcal A$ is a linear map, and that the original set you are observing is precisely the image of $\mathcal A$, that is

$$\mathcal A(\mathbb R^3) = \{(a+b+c) + (a-b)x + (a+b)x^2|a,b,c\in\mathbb R\}.$$ Now, observe the matrix $A$ that is associated with the mapping $A$ in the standard bases of both vector spaces. Note that $$\begin{align}
\mathcal A(1,0,0)&=1+x+x^2\\ 
\mathcal A(0,1,0)&=1-x+x^2\\ 
\mathcal A(0,0,1)&=1
\end{align}$$
which means, by definition, that

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&-1&0\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, using some linear algebra, you may remember that a mapping between two equally dimensional spaces is surjective **if and only if** it is bijective, which happens if and only if the matrix representing it is of full rank, i.e. if the matrix $A$ (which we saw twice before!) is of full rank.

Comment: Super clear answer. I'm actually not that familiar with writing polynomials as vectors. I would typically take $\{1+x+x^2,-x+x^2,1\}$ and then multiply it by $a,b,c$ in that order to get the span, and then do row reduction, setting the RHS equal to 0. Why can you represent those polynomials in that vector notation form?

Comment: @beginner By definition, in the basis $e_1,e_2,\dots e_n$, the vector $\alpha_1e_1+\cdots+\alpha_n e_n$ is represented as the column vector $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\vdots\\\alpha_n\end{bmatrix}$.